# How to Group By after Order By without any aggregate function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the unique records after sorting the data in specific order.

The data table looks like this

`SELECT * FROM category_products;`

[image]

Now, requirement is to Order By the records on category_id and then select unique rows of  product_id. I wrote the below query to sort the records

```
SELECT * FROM category_products ORDER BY  category_id=2 desc;
```

[image]

When I try to Group By this sorted results with product_id, then the results aren't in right order. Even tried Group By clause in both child query and same query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        category_products
    ORDER BY category_id = 2 DESC) AS cat_products
GROUP BY cat_products.product_id;
```

Current Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

The result isn't the right one for which I'm looking for. Kindly help me guys, this doesn't seems to that tricky thing but I'm kind of stuck with it.

Comment: Can you update the question to show your expected output? It's not clear (to me, at least) from your question what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Martin I have added an image for Expected output

Comment: Where are category_id=1 in the expected output?

Comment: How do you order the results?  I'm not clear on why the result set you want is produced currently

Comment: @tcadidot0 I have removed the category_id=2 from Order By clause, it was just making the scenario a little more difficult to understand.

Comment: @Martin I'm trying to order products with category_id =2 and then select the unique rows with product_id from that sorted results

Comment: your order by criteria says that you want category_id 2 to be the first. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Martin In the second image, the output of Order By category_id =2 query have product_id repeating but with different category_id. I need to pick unique product_id rows from this ordered list with ordered category_id which is being showed in expected output image.

Comment: @kiks73 yes, after that I like to distinct the rows depending upon product_id and select the first occurring row against each product_id

Comment: @WasimBajwa my answer should be what you are looking for

Comment: @kiks73 Your query are returning the right results, since this scenario is a part of a bigger query for which I'm lookin for a more of one liner query using Group By or some other thing. I'll wait for that, if that's not achievable then I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> requirement is to Order By the records on category_id and then select
>   unique rows of product_id. I wrote the below query to sort the records

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
       ,(SELECT category_id 
         FROM category_products 
         WHERE product_id = CP.product_id 
         ORDER BY category_id 
         LIMIT 1) AS cat_id
FROM category_products CP;
```

you need a SUBQUERY with an ORDER BY and LIMIT 1

Comment: I have run your query and although it returns the unique product_id but the category_id isn't the one which should be after sorting.

Comment: @WasimBajwa you need to specify better which category_id you want for the unique product_id. The one I provided should be the lower

Comment: Figured that out. Is it possible not to use the sub query, may be through Group By or some other thing?

Comment: Actually this scenario is happening in a fairly complex query and using a nested query their can increase the complexity

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear on how you aim to achieve this but from my understanding you can maybe create a custom sorting column to fulfill your requirement. See example below:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN category_id=2 THEN 1 
            WHEN category_id=4 THEN 2 
            ELSE 99 END AS rownum
FROM category_products 
ORDER BY rownum, product_id;
```

I'm using `CASE` to define a custom `rownum` and use it in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Demo fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kAcGYtng2RWCf2Yhn5N1C9/0